# How many soul points do I get for surviving in die2nite?

Tags: die2nite

My best town so far in die2nite seems like it will come to an end with day 9. How many soul points will I get when I've died? Does it only count for days survived or will I get extra points for doing special stuff (like doing heroic actions, eating a cat, etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've already answered this one before in a different question, so here we go:

The formula for soul points is [image: 0.5(n+n^2)] where n is the amount of days you lived **fully** in a particular town. Basically, you add up the amount of days, which means that by day 9 you'll have 1+2+...+9 = 45 soul points.

As the [official help page](http://www.die2nite.com/#help/death_and_soul_points) states:

> A day is considered "lived in full" *if you survive the night or die from consequences arising from the zombie attack at 23:59.* Death of any other kind will render the day invalid.

If you die from poisoned water on day 10 for example, you will earn points only for the 9 days you survived fully, so again 45 points.

Answer (score 1):

If you die to the zombie attack for day n, you get 1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n +1)/2 soul point.

If you die for any other reason during the midnight attack (or during  the day!), your last day isn't counted. You hence get 1 + 2 + ... + n - 1 = n(n -1)/2 soul points.